# Flatten dependencies

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I have `dependency` `A` which has `parrentId` of other `dependency` `B` which has `parrentId` of `dependency` `C` which has `parrentId` of`request` `R`

some other `dependecies` have shorter connection to request like `A -> B -> R`

having `dependency` `A` how to get `request` object ?
How to go from the lowest `dependency` to the parrent `request` ?

I thought this can be achived by using `operation_Id` but this is not true, when there is a chain of apis call, where one api call another, there will be multiple request with the same `operation_id`

Comment: Is `parrentId` a custom property? Can you show some ouput from kusto?

Comment: @PeterBons no it is not a custom property (exactly name is operation_ParentId) and it idetifies the depenency parent (either other dependency or the request) this is like a tree and I am looking way to flattern it

Comment: The flattened list can be generated by querying based on  the `operation_Id`. When a request is performed both the request and correlated dependency telemetry share the same `operation_Id`

Comment: @PeterBons this is not true when you have chain of apis like one api calls another , there will be many reuqest but all with the same operation_id

Comment: yes, but then you can take the oldest one based on the timestamp to get the initial request.

Comment: @PeterBons well more or less, but this is not accurate, this way you will take sometimes timestamp from other request then the one given dependency is binded.

Answer (score 2):

The flattened list could be built with 3 joins:

```
datatable (id: int, parrentId: int, name: string)[
1, int(null), 'R1',
2, 1, 'C1',
3, 2, 'B1',
4, 3, 'A1',
5, int(null), 'R2',
6, 5, 'B2',
7, 6, 'A2',
]
| as T
| where isnull(parrentId)
| join kind=leftouter (T) on $left.id == $right.parrentId
| join kind=leftouter (T) on $left.id1 == $right.parrentId
| join kind=leftouter (T) on $left.id2 == $right.parrentId
| project request=id, lowest= coalesce(id3, id2, id1)
```

Comment: you know only last dependency id so you need to start from bottom. also there might be even 7 children between

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the application, the task can also be solved with the scan operator.

```
datatable (t: int, id: int, parrentId: int, name: string)[
1, 1, int(null), 'R1',
2, 2, 1, 'C1',
3, 3, 2, 'B1',
4, 4, 3, 'A1',
5, 5, int(null), 'R2',
6, 6, 5, 'B2',
7, 7, 6, 'A2',
]
| sort by t
| scan declare (leaf:int) with (
step Child output=none: name startswith 'A' or id == Child.parrentId
 => leaf= coalesce(Child.leaf, id);
step Root: isnull(parrentId) and id == Child.parrentId => leaf= Child.leaf;
)
```

The [scan operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator) needs sorted events, from the last dependency event to the request event. The step Child matches the last dependency (leaf) and the following dependencies. The step Root matches the request. Only the step Root has a output with the additional column leaf. If you do not need the leaf id in the result the query can be simplified.

Comment: could you add explenation how does it work ?

Comment: first problme is that i still need to build the table like you use in this ( so i have to use many many joins, second for milons of point this is very very slow